# Use curl in php script

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm trying to create a script that will delete all user properties for a particular individual. I'm able to use an api call to get the users' properties. And I'm trying use a delete api to remove each property. But I'm having an issue doing so. Below is the code:

```
$delete = "http://www.ourwiki.com/@api/DELETE:users/$user_id/properties/%s";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

foreach($xml->property as $property) {
  $name = $property['name']; // the name is stored in the attribute
  file_get_contents(sprintf($delete, $name));
}
```

I believe I need to use curl to perform the actual delete. Here is an example of that command (property=something):

```
curl -u username:password -X DELETE -i http://ourwiki.com/@api/users/=john_smith@ourwiki.com/properties/something
```

-u Provides external user authentication.

-X Specifies the HTTP request method.

-i Outputs the HTTP response headers. Useful for debugging.

Is this something that I can incorporate right into the existing script? Or is there something else I need to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**update:**

```
<?php

$user_id="john_smith@ourwiki.com";

$url=('http://aaron:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/deki/users/=john_smith@ourwiki.com/properties');
$xmlString=file_get_contents($url);

$delete = "http://aaron:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/deki/DELETE:users/$user_id/properties/%s";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

 function curl_fetch($url,$username,$password,$method='DELETE')
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // returns output as a string instead of echoing it
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password"); // if your server requires basic auth do this
    return  curl_exec($ch);
}

foreach($xml->property as $property) {
  $name = $property['name']; // the name is stored in the attribute
  curl_fetch(sprintf($delete, $name),'aaron','12345');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [php curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), or shell out to curl using [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php).

If curl is already enabled on you web server, go with php curl. If you cant install php-curl copy a command line version of curl and you are good to go.

In php-curl to set the delete method do:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');`

**edit**

Something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.ourwiki.com/@api/whatever/url/you/want/or/need");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // returns output as a string instead of echoing it
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password"); // if your server requires basic auth do this
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

**edit2**

stick that above code in a function:

```
function curl_fetch($url,$username,$password,$method='DELETE')
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // returns output as a string instead of echoing it
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password"); // if your server requires basic auth do this
    return  curl_exec($ch);
}
```

and replace the call to `file_get_contents()` in your script with the new function.

`curl_fetch(sprintf($delete, $name),'aaron','12345');`

**Done.**

Comment: When I run phpinfo it appears that curl is enabled. So does this mean I can simply run that command within the php script. If so, how is that actually done? I'm not very familiar with curl unfortunately.

Comment: Where do the url and credentials belong? And how do I actually call the delete method?

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot. Does this mean that I need to call $ch instead of $delete from within the for loop?

Comment: @Aaron You need to put the whole chunk of code I posted in the loop.

Comment: Ok, I thought that was the case. I just wasn't sure what to do with my existing delete. Since it is in the file_get_contents and would be using the current api "delete" call not the curl one. Do I need to make any other changes?

Comment: Don't worry I accepted :) I still do seem to be having an issue somewhere. Can you check out my update above? I've included everything I have so far. When I run the script, I'm not getting any errors now. However when I manually run the api call to get the users properties everything still appears there and has not been deleted. Any ideas why this might be happening? Also, I did see in a log file that it tells me ProcessRequest: feature not found(DELETE URI: http://localhost:8081/deki/DELETE:users/john_smith@ourwiki.com/properties/ourwiki.userprofile) Is this a syntax issue possibly?

Comment: The second and third parameters to the delete function shoud be the password for the webservice. I just put aaron 1234 as a sample. if the webservice doesn't take a username or password, comment out the liine in the function. if they do, put in hte correct user/pass.

Comment: I thought that was the case and I used my credentials in place for the  user/pass but seems something else is still going on :(

Comment: Looks like it was having difficulty because the @ in the email and # in the property needed to be encoded. How would I modify the script so that the properties use %23 each time it loops through? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are looking for the curl function calls in php, including [curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: I looked up curl_setopt, I'm just not exactly sure how to run the command based on my example. Like how do I supply the URL and the credentials?

Comment: Thanks, any chance you know how i would properly call delete? As of now my for loop is using the old api call for $delete. I'm just not sure how to use the code that he provided in my example.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://php.net/curl